# Ruby - display backtick output on console

Tags: ruby, ansible

In Ruby I'm using backticks to execute (many) shell commands. How do I get the shell command output displayed on the console?

A bit more detail. If I run an (ansible) command like the following, I get **lots** of scrolling output on the console:

```
% ansible-playbook config.yml -e foo=bar -e baz=qux

PLAY [base setup] **************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.99.66.210]

... etc, etc
```

However if I execute the same command from Ruby (using backticks) I don't see any output on the console:

```
# cmd = ansible-playbook config.yml -e foo=bar -e baz=qux
`#{cmd}`
```

Which is unfortunate, as I'd like to see the output in order to debug. I could redirect the output from the Ruby script to a (tailed) log file, however I want to see the output as it happens.

Comment: I don't think you need to interpolate `cmd` with `#{}`

Comment: You need to `puts \`#{cmd}\``, but I'm not sure if it will show anything until it completes. Otherwise use [popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [David K-J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4537473/david-k-j)'s comment, as well as [Ruby—Open3.popen3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325624/ruby-open3-popen3-how-to-print-the-output)

The solution for me was [Open3#popen2e](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e), for example:

```
# cmd = ansible-playbook config.yml -e foo=bar -e baz=qux
puts cmd
if execute then
  puts "Executing..."
  Dir.chdir("..") do
    Open3.popen2e(cmd) do |i,oe,t|
      oe.each { |line| puts line }
    end
  end
end
```